# Unwanted separator is showing on iOS 7

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7

I am running my app on iOS 5, 6 and 7.
On iOS 5 and 6 my tableview doesn't have any separator, but when running app on iOS 7 separator is appearing between cells.

I used following code, but still the separator visible on iOS 7

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorStyle:)]) {
   [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone]; 
}
```

Also, I used this code :

```
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)]) {
   [tableView setSeparatorInset:UIEdgeInsetsZero];
 }
```

I put above code in ViewDidLoad method. But nothing work for me.

Is there any other way to hide/remove the separator in iOS 7.

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Please share info on the TableStyle (Grouped / Plain) and also Screenshots if possible.

Comment: Just check in the xib also whether the separator is default or what

Comment: I am using Plain tableStyle. I have added the snapshot of table view attribute

Answer (score 0):

Don't use your

```
if ([self.tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorStyle:)])
```

the property `separatorStyle` is available for all iOS.

```
@property(nonatomic) UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle separatorStyle;              // default is UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine
```

I use this in my code and work perfectly with iOS7 :

```
_table.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Comment: I have already used Separator style None in nib file. Please see the the image attached in the question.

Comment: I tried what you did (on a storyboard), and separators are gone. You should have done something else wrong. Can you give more code or details ?

Comment: Thanks... I am able to resolve this bug by setting the separatorStyle and the background color.

Comment: It looks more than weird, I didn't touch to background color in my tests

Comment: Yes.. you are right, it's weird. I also able to do it on sample project without background colour.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the separator color to clear

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the inset on the cells:

```
cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, CGRectGetWidth(cell.bounds), 0, 0);
```